# How can i use tcl to create xls file with multisheets and colored boxes as per requirement?

Tags: excel, tcl

I am using Linux operating System. and my most of the application is in TCL. I am thinking of adding a module to it for creating xls file with multiple sheets and colored boxes as per requirement. Is there a way by which i can created xls file? csv will not help me for the task. Any Help/Suggestion/Keyword will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This i made it done by simple hit and trial of perl and half day learning of Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

http://homepage.tinet.ie/~jmcnamara/perl/WriteExcel.html

Creating perl file using tcl data and at the end executing the perl script. Final output of xls file generated. Thanks everyone for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

The excel formats are *formidably* tricky (only CSV is remotely easy to handle, and that's because it doesn't do much). I'd use Apache POI for this, even bearing in mind that it is Java code and so likely to be a bit awkward to integrate with your Tcl code.

If you were able to run on Windows instead, the TCOM package would let you talk to a running Excel instance to do the work more directly. That package is platform-specific though…